# Is the characteristic equation in ODE the same characteristic equation in linear algebra?

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Can someone show me whether this "characteristic equation" thing in ODE is the same characteristic equation that we derive for a matrix?

For example, given $y'' + 2y = 0$, the characteristic equation is $\lambda^2 = -2$

How does this equation correspond to those of a matrix?

Comment: what what what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's re-write the ODE as a first-order system:

$$\begin{align*}
y_1 &= y\\
y_2 &= y' \\
y'_1 &= y_2 \\
y'_2 &= 2y_1.
\end{align*}$$

This is a linear system, so let's let $\mathbf{y} = \begin{pmatrix} y_1 \\ y_2 \end{pmatrix}$. Then,

$$\mathbf{y}' = \underbrace{\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -2 & 0 \end{pmatrix}}_{=A} \mathbf{y}.$$

Now, we can use the matrix exponential to solve this ODE in the usual way, but rather let's explore the characteristic equation of the matrix $A$:

$$A-\lambda I = \begin{pmatrix} -\lambda & 1 \\ -2 & -\lambda\end{pmatrix}\\
\det A-\lambda I = (-\lambda)^2 + 2.$$

Setting this equal to zero, we get

$$\lambda^2 +2 = 0$$

which is precisely the characteristic equation obtained through the "traditional" method of converting derivatives of $y$ to powers of $\lambda$.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose you start with a polynomial
$$
                       p(w) = w^{n}+a_{n-1}w^{n-1}+a_{n-2}w^{n-2}+\cdots+a_{1}w+a_{0}.
$$
Consider the differential equation $p(D)f=0$ where $D=\frac{d}{dx}$ is the differentiation operator. That is, consider the differential equation
$$
             f^{(n)}+a_{n-1}f^{(n-1)}+a_{n-2}f^{(n-2)}+\cdots+a_{1}f'+a_{0}f=0.
$$
The solution space $M$ of this differential equation is a finite-dimensional linear space of dimension $n$, and this solution space is invariant under the operator $D$. So $D$ is represented by a matrix $[D]$ on $M$, and the characteristic polynomial of $[D]$ is $p$. In fact the minimal and characteristic polynomials of $[D]$ are both $p$, which is independently interesting.

**For your case:** The solution space of $(D^{2}+2I)f=0$ is a linear subspace $M$ which is invariant under $D$. When $D$ is represented as a matrix $[D]$ on the solution space $M$, it has characteristic polynomial and minimal $p(x)=x^{2}+2$. For example, one such basis is $\{ e^{i\sqrt{2}x},e^{-i\sqrt{2}x}\}$, and the matrix $[D]$ in this basis is
$$
        [D]=\left[\begin{array}{cc}i\sqrt{2} & 0 \\ 0 & -i\sqrt{2}\end{array}\right],
$$
which has minimal and characteristic polynomial $(\lambda-i\sqrt{2})(\lambda+i\sqrt{2})=\lambda^{2}+2$.